# A datetime equivalent in java.sql ? (is there a java.sql.datetime ?)

Tags: java, mysql, sql, datetime, jdbc

So far, I have not found a clear answer to this.

I'd like to know what the equivalent is for a SQL type DATETIME and the java type, using a PreparedStatement.

I have found: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/StandardSQLDataTypeswithTheirJavaEquivalents.htm

But it states that SQL type "DATETIME" is the same as sql.date, but when looking at the SQL date docs (http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html), it says the time is truncated (all zeros).

What I want is to be able to specify a `preparedStatement.setDateTime()` or some sort.

The only other way I see is using a timestamp, but that would require me to change the column type, while I cannot imagine someone else never had this problem before?

Any hints?

Edit: I am using MYSQL.

Comment: mysql documentation official mapping:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html

Answer (score 148, accepted):

The java.sql package has three date/time types:

- [`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) - A date only (no time part)
- [`java.sql.Time`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html) - A time only (no date part)
- [`java.sql.Timestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) - Both date and time

You want the last one: `java.sql.Timestamp`.

If you are using these types, you don't need to call a specific setter; just use:

```
java.util.Date date = new Date();
Object param = new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime());
// The JDBC driver knows what to do with a java.sql type:
preparedStatement.setObject(param);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. How did you find out that these types match with certain SQL types? I am a bit troubled, since my query works fine with using NOW(), but not using a date instance of "now" in java and use it as a timestamp?

Comment: I found out that I had made a mistake in the query. I missed something obvious. Your answer is the solution, thanks a bunch! :)

Comment: you mentioned `java.sql.Date - A date only (no time)` then how come `date.getTime()` returns time?

Comment: @FunsukWangadu because `java.sql.Date` is a subclass of `java.util.Date` (as is `java.sql.Time`), so even though it isn't a "moment in time", it inherits all the methods as if it were. It's a design flaw in the java API.

Comment: plus one, especially for answering my follow up question about setting the preparedstatement!

Answer (score 7):

The equivalent of MS SQL Server or MySQL DATETIME data type or Oracle DATE data type is java.sql.Timestamp.

Comment: thx. I am using MYSQL though, so I have updated the question.

Comment: Update answer to include MySQL.

Answer (score 3):

In Java we have java.util.Date to handle both Date and Time values.

In SQL, you have commonly Dates (only dates), Time (only time) and DateTime/Timestamp (date and time).

In your Java program, usually you'll always have java.util.Date, so each time you're setting Dates/Times/DateTimes in PreparedStatements, always choose exactly which one you need, according to the database.

Comment: How do you retrieve a DateTime object in UTC (not in server's timezone) ?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with my Mysql having SQL date and locally in my app i only had Date

I solved like this

```
java.sql.Date dataStartSql = new java.sql.Date(start.getTime());
```

After that used the setDate normally, and I used a getTimestamp to retrive the first value.

where start is a Date object.