# converting java time to sqldate in query

Tags: mysql, sql

java datetime (date.getTime()) is stored as string in mysql field.
How can we convert this to sql date using sql query. I am using mysql database.
Is there any sql function available?
For example - This is stored (1416231812348) for today's date in db.

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: where 1416231812348 is stored. mysql datetime field??

Comment: No, as string it is stored (varchar).

Comment: possible duplicate of [A datetime equivalent in java.sql ? (is there a java.sql.datetime ?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777810/a-datetime-equivalent-in-java-sql-is-there-a-java-sql-datetime)

Comment: No, it is no duplicate of that.It is not java related question, but mysql query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is returning the date as a long, to convert it you can use:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(event_time) FROM MY_TABLE
```

If you get an error, try the following (after testing, I can see that your data is stored in milliseconds so you need to use this method):

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(event_time/1000) FROM MY_TABLE
```

(Change event_time to be the field name in your table and MY_TABLE to be the table name.)

Here is a [SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/48776) that shows it working.

Here is an answer that gives you formatting options as well:
http://notsoyellowstickies.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/converting-long-into-datetime-mysql.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a java.sql package, that has time included. You can send it straight into your database without needing to convert it.

This may be a more pre-emptive solution than converting a date string from Java, into time in MySQL.

A similar question was answered and may be able to help you out here:

[A datetime equivalent in java.sql ? (is there a java.sql.datetime ?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777810/a-datetime-equivalent-in-java-sql-is-there-a-java-sql-datetime)

Answer (score 0):

most probably you have recorded from:

```
System.currentTimeMillis()
```

so:

```
select DATE_FORMAT ( from_unixtime( your_table_field / 1000 ) , '%e %b %Y');
```

you can change the date format as you like.