# Java: How to Convert LocalDateTime value to Date and Preserve Time Portion

Tags: java, java-8

I have a need to convert from a LocalDateTime with both a date and time component to a Date without losing the time part. I have been doing something like:

```
LocalDateTime ldt = //some full date-time value

Date date = java.util.Date.valueOf(ldt.toLocalDate());
```

, but am obviously losing the time part..I see there is also a LocalDateTime.toLocalTime(), however I need both date and time together.

Thank you

Comment: what about using `ldt.toDate()`?

Comment: can't you save the date in a separate string and then retrieve it later?

Comment: *losing the time part*, sql.Date has NO time part indeed so

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LocalDateTime to java.sql.Date in java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45102667/localdatetime-to-java-sql-date-in-java-8)

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to convert to `java.util.Date` instead?

Comment: I meant java.util.Date. I apologize. I have updated my original question with the correction. thanks as I still want an answer.

Comment: @azro No not a duplicate of [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45102667/localdatetime-to-java-sql-date-in-java-8). This Question is apparently using `java.sql.Date` by accident, the other question deliberately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`java.util.Date` does hold time component if you provide it. But in the first place why would you want to work with old Date rather then keep with the new java 8 `java.time` package? In any case to answer your question I suggest to retrieve epoch milliseconds and then create your `Date` from that. So  It would look something like this:

```
long epoch = ZonedDateTime.of(ldt, ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli();
Date date = new Date(epoch);
```

Due to request from Basil Bourque - an explanation why `ZonedDateTime` is needed: in order to extract epoch - number of milliseconds from "1.1.1970 00:00:00+0000" you will need to convert `LocalDateTime` (which is not absolute time and could mean a different instant in time in different locations) to `ZonedDateTime` that also holds a location and thus is absolute time. Thus from `ZonedDateTime` you can extract the epoch.

Comment: You should explain why the `ZonedDateTime` is necessary.

Comment: @Timothy Clotwothy - I am glad it worked. I still would recommend to stick with new java.time package rather then use legacy date-time classes. Also if the answer helped you could you also up-vote it? :)

Answer (score 4):

That is because `java.sql.Date` doesn't include the time.

You could use the class `java.sql.Timestamp` instead, which includes both date and time.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

Apparently, you inadvertently used the class `java.sql.Date` where you thought you were using `java.util.Date`. But that issue is moot: **use *java.time* classes** instead of  those terrible old date-time classes.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , myLocalDateTime ) ;
```

…and…

```
myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class )
```

## Check your imports

Apparently you are inadvertently using `java.sql.Date` which pretends to have no time of day. Unfortunately, it’s terrible class design inherits from `java.util.Date` which does have a time-of-day. So the `sql` sets its time to 00:00:00. And the documentation tells us to ignore the fact of their inheritance. Terrible design, terrible names, terrible classes all around.

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

For all these reasons and more, these old classes were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes.

## JDBC 4.2

As of JDBC 4.2, we can exchange *java.time* classes with the database. No need to ever touch `java.util.Date`, `java.sql.Date`, `java.sql.Timestamp` again.

## Without zone

A [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) should be stored in a database column of a type akin to the SQL-standard type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`. These type intentionally lack any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. As such, these types *cannot* represent a moment, *cannot* hold a specific point on the timeline. These are likely *not* what you want in most business scenarios.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , myLocalDateTime ) ;
```

Retrieval:

```
myLocalDateTime = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class ) ;
```

If they cannot represent a moment, what good are these types? In what scenarios is the use of `java.time.LocalDateTime` class & `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` column appropriate? These three:

- The **zone or offset is unknown**.
  This is bad. This is faulty data. Analogous to having a price/cost without knowing the currency. You should be rejecting such data, not storing it.
- The **intention is “everywhere”**, as in, every time zone.
  For example, a corporate policy that states “All our factories will break for lunch at 12:30" means the factory in Delhi will break hours before the factory in Düsseldorf which breaks hours before the factory in Detroit.
- A specific moment in the future is intended, but we are **afraid of politicians redefining the time zone**.
  Governments change the rules of their time zones with [surprising frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Russia#Russian_Federation) and with surprisingly [little warning](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-34631326) or even [no warning at all](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-44010705). So if you want to book an appointment at 3 PM on a certain date, and you really mean 3 PM regardless of any crazy decision a government might make in the interim, then store a `LocalDateTime`. To print a report or display a calendar, dynamically apply a time zone (`ZoneId`) to generate a specific moment (`ZonedDateTime` or `Instant`). This must be done on-the-fly rather than storing the value.

## With zone

In contrast, to store a moment, use a database column of a type akin to the SQL-standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. For such a column, in Java use [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class. This class represents a moment in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond).

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , myInstant ) ;
```

Retrieval:

```
myInstant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;
```

## Applying time zone

If you are certain your `LocalDateTime` was meant implicitly to represent a moment in the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone), apply a `ZoneId` to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = myLocalDateTime.atZone( z ) ;
```

Then extract a `Instant` object to adjust into [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant();
```

Store in database.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , instant ) ;
```

Retrieve from database.

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: I seemed to have caused a lot of confusion. I wrote the question wrong. I was always using java.util.Date. Anyway, the question has been answered. Thanks for your time though.