# getYesterdayDate_yyyy_MM_dd() this method with return type java.sql.date

Tags: java

i want to create a method java.sql.Date getYesterdayDate_yyyy_MM_dd() using java 8 get yesterday date and formatted it then it is converted in string how to convert string in sql date i try date.valuof is throwing exception

Comment: Please post your question properly since it's not at all comprehensible!

Comment: Why do you want to convert a String to date and then date to String again ? You can use Date formatter utility class: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Comment: `Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure you tag your question with proper labels (programming language, relevant technologies etc). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: You can’t. A `java.sql.Date` hasn’t got, as in cannot have a format. Also that class is an age-old hack to try (not very successfully) to disguise a `java.util.Date` as a date without time of day. Don’t use that class if there’s any way you can avoid it. Use  `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: I’m immodest enough to recommend [my own answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52485250/5772882). I treat `java.sql.Date` near the bottom.

Comment: Think of this as [an XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). What makes you think that you want or need a `java.sql.Date` with format `yyyy_MM_dd`? Give us some context, please.

Answer (score 1):

```
LocalDateTime yesterday = LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(1);

  DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");               
  String formattedDate = yesterday.format(formatter); 

  System.out.println("formattedDate="+formattedDate);

  // formattedDate=27-05-2019 11:58:35
```

Comment: after formatter it is converted in string and i want this formatted date in java.sql.date  type after parse it is giving exception

Comment: my console exception is here- Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2019-05-27"
 at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
 at com.wtmit.crmws.util.CRMWSDateTimeUtil.getYesterdayDate_yyyy_MM_dd(CRMWSDateTimeUtil.java:74)
 at com.wtmit.crmws.util.CRMWSDateTimeUtil.main(CRMWSDateTimeUtil.java:47)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45102667/localdatetime-to-java-sql-date-in-java-8/45102795

Comment: `java.sql.Date SQL= new java.sql.Date(yesterday.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()
              .toEpochMilli());`

Comment: it is working but with this i want formatter also in yyyy_MM_dd format

Comment: `String sqlFormattedDate=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(SQLdate);`

Comment: @sachinrai Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: @priyankagupta It’s not hard: `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy_MM_dd")`. Only you can have a format only in a string, not in a `LocalDateTime`, `java.sql.Date` or any other date-time object.

Comment: Indeed, @sachinrai, and I had already briefly considered upvoting for exactly that reason. However, you’re not providing the format asked for, nor any explanation, so not at the moment.